# Prolog: How to create all possible permutations with repetition give a list of objects

Tags: list, prolog, permutation

First of all, excuse me for being a noob at Prolog.
All I want to achieve is to
Create a predicate that
 - **for objects [0,1]**
 - **Given a desired Length** (for example 3)
 - **Finds all possible permutations (with repetition) of given Length** (0 can be added multiple times, 1 can be added multiple times, no problem if I have a list of same objects for example...)

*Example:*

```
? myPermutation(3, [0,1], L).
L = [0,0,0]
next->
L = [0,0,1]
next->
L = [0,1,0]
next->
L = [0,1,1]
....
next->
L = [1,1,1]
```

Can someone ***please*** help me with that?
Thanks a lot...

Hint: I am thinking something using the delete predicate... Something like giving the List of Objects and question Prolog for all the possible ways to delete an object from [0,1].

Comment: I have that predicate:

del(X,[X|Tail],Tail).
del(X,[Y|Tail],[Y|Tail1]):-
   del(X,Tail,Tail1).


and I query
del(X, [0,1], _).

which returns
X = 0
X = 1
false

Via backtracking.

So I guess we still need a predicate with accumulator, that given a length, using the del as proposed, prepares a list of [0,1,...,1] and backtracks to all solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach is a bit complicated. You could simply write something like:

```
eval([],_).
eval([H|T],Set):-member(H,Set),eval(T,Set).

myPermutation(N, Set, L):-length(L,N), eval(L,Set).
```

The above solution uses the `length/2` predicate to set the length of the output list and calls `eval/2` predicate which just iterates recursively the lists and forces each element of the list to be member of the given Set.
Example:

```
?- myPermutation(3, [0,1], L).
L = [0, 0, 0] ;
L = [0, 0, 1] ;
L = [0, 1, 0] ;
L = [0, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 0, 0] ;
L = [1, 0, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 0] ;
L = [1, 1, 1].
```

Also you can make more general queries like:

```
?- myPermutation(3, S, [0,0,1]).
S = [0, 1|_G3426] ;
S = [0, _G3425, 1|_G3429] ;
S = [0, _G3425, _G3428, 1|_G3432] ;
S = [0, _G3425, _G3428, _G3431, 1|_G3435] ;
S = [0, _G3425, _G3428, _G3431, _G3434, 1|_G3438] .
(and goes on...)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! I will accept this answer, as is even better than what I asked (takes a set of objects, not just 0,1).

Comment: Glad to help !!